# Taking a non-negative number and outputs a pair

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function lbs2lboz(p) that takes a non-negative number,  p , that represents a weight in pounds and outputs a pair  (l,o) such that l is an integer and p=l+o/16.

I am not sure on how to do this problem or rather how to start it.

The output should look something like this:

```
>>> lbs2lboz(2.7)
(2, 11.200000000000003)
>>> lbs2lboz(2)
(2, 0)

def lbs2lbox (p):
    answer = p = l+o/16
```

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def lbs2lboz(p):
    l = int(p)
    o = 16*(p-l)
    return (l, o)
```

Gives:

```
>>> lbs2lboz(2.7)
(2, 11.200000000000003)
>>> lbs2lboz(2)
(2, 0)
```

The way it works is:

- Calculate `l` by truncating `p`.
- If `p = l + o / 16`, then `o = 16p - 16l`, or `o = 16(p-l)`.
- Return as a tuple.

Comment: Thank You, I also have another question.

Comment: Write a function oz2lboz(oz) that takes a non-negative number,  oz , that represents a weight in ounces and outputs a pair  (l,o) such that l is an integer and oz=l*16+o.

Comment: That seems like a similar question, just set `l=int(oz)` and `o=oz-l*16`.